# Badge "Pergunta Notável" não seria significado menor que "Pergunta Popular"?

Tags: debate, status-recusado

Temos as seguintes medalhas:
[image: medalhas_view]

Se pararmos para pensar, não acham que algo "popular" seria mais visto do que algo "notável"?

Pois, se você é um desconhecido então alguém passa a te: "Notar", logo você é notável.

Se várias pessoas passam a te "Notar", você se torna "Popular".

Se realmente muitas pessoas passam a te "Notar" você se torna "Famoso".

**Notável**, agrega mais valor a um trabalho bem feito, melhor reconhecido, porém a medalha não tem como objetivo dizer que sua questão foi bem feita, ou que mereça reconhecimento, ela só quer dizer que sua questão foi apenas "vista" por muitos usuários, isso não quer dizer que sua questão foi digna de reconhecimento notável.

Por isso notável neste contexto se torna menor, pois, "Popular" em questão de "mais pessoas viram" tem mais valor que "notável".

Esta é minha opinião, o que acham disso?

Comment: Mesmo que esteja errada, o que discordo, seria um problema menor. Está assim em toda rede, não vale à pena mudar.

Comment: Se vale a pena ou não, aí é decisão da direção do SO, opiniões estão aí para serem expostas, só visam o melhor da comunidade, em todos os quesitos, por mais simples que sejam.

Answer (score 6):

Já eu discordo dessa opinião. Como você usou uma metáfora com pessoas, eu vou seguir pelo mesmo caminho. Uma pessoa popular em uma cidade, é alguém que conhece muitos cidadãos e fez uma coisa ou outra para aquela população que o tornou conhecido por todos.
Uma pessoa notável, em uma cidade, é uma pessoa que teve um trabalho amplamente reconhecido pela população e por isso se tornou uma pessoa de "trabalho notável".

No entanto, a última medalha que faz o seu ponto de vista ser válido. Como é utilizado pergunta famosa, ser popular fica num "âmbito maior" que ser notável. Só que, o que eu imagino é que, algo notável tem muito mais valia que algo popular. Seria como um relógio popular e um relógio notável, por exemplo. O relógio popular só quer dizer que muita gente tem, um relógio notável quer dizer que aquele relógio possuí características que o diferencia dos outros relógios. Ou seja, na minha concepção, algo notável tem uma importância maior que algo popular.

Comment: Mas a sua afirmação está correta, porém, a medalha tem o objetivo de ser "vista por muitas pessoas" o que não quer dizer que a questão em si seja boa, que mereça reconhecimento. Por isso minha opinião do qual `Notavel < Popular` em questão de `Visualizações` estaria correta.

Comment: Editei minha questão, veja acima, mencionei algo relacionado ao que você disse, e obrigado por expor seu ponto de vista ;)

Comment: Acho que a graduação está correta. Sua primeiro parágrafo é perfeito. Esse ´o entendimento correto de "notável". Discordo do segundo. Cientistas são notáveis mas não são famosos. Fama é algo "estelar", está acima da própria vida. É o reconhecimento maior. No entanto nem toda fama vem de forma justa. Não importa, fama é fama, até má fama :) Fernandinho Beira-mar é popular entre bandidos, é notável criminoso e famoso na sociedade (pelo menos brasileira).

Comment: e não é este o sentido de uma medalha ganha por pessoas que simplesmente clicaram na sua questão e abriram-na, sem talvez, nem sequer ter lido? :)